# Google captcha not working even after replacing the actual keys

Tags: php, laravel, captcha

I'm working on a Laravel project, which is in a test server now. In the actual server the google captcha works well. But in the test server even after replacing the captcha key in the .env, the same old error message

> 'ERROR for site owner: Invalid key type' displays.

Please find the URL [here](http://www.bespokesolutions.us/infocytosis/public/register) where the error occurs.

Comment: Are you working on localhost as a test server or on a live server  ?

Comment: you also have `validation.min.string` error on your site, check here validations https://laravel.com/docs/4.2/validation

Answer (score 2):

The error clearly says that

> ERROR for site owner: Invalid key type

You have to make sure that you use the key type for reCaptcha v2 from your Google account (not v3).